# Asus K751LJ-TY316T touchpad not detected / working under Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

There is no "touchpad" section in system settings->mouse and touch-pad. Fn+F9 just shows a crossed out touch-pad symbol.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]  
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ HID 04b4:0033                             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]  
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ USB Camera                                id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
[    2.065554] pnp: PnP ACPI init  
[    2.065792] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs SYN0a2d SYN0a00 SYN0002 PNP0f13 (active)
[    2.065825] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs ATK3001 PNP030b (active)  
[    2.065940] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)  
[    2.066860] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 8 devices  
3.19.0-47-generic
```

Comment: What model laptop?

Comment: see thread title...

Answer (score -1):

You should try to get a usb mouse and update ubuntu. The update will fix your issue!

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

after a restart you should be up and running! Good Luck, Let me know if you need more help

Comment: Im using a usb mouse and an updated OS...

Comment: by updating your system you allow it to find any errors in drivers and it also checks what drivers are still needed. hence the update upgrade.

Comment: your a troll .. stop posting questions if your not really trying to get help. i can tell your trolling by your short answers.im flagging you!

Comment: @hectorVill updating the system won't help at all if you don't have the required drivers or if something is wrong. I'm downvoting your answer and I hope you delete this "your a troll" comments of yours.

Comment: @blurple Don't worry about this kind of mean comments. You're always welcome to ask ay questions here and we'll always try to give you the best we can. I'll make some research about your problem and try to answer your question as soon as possible.